# Using PepperFlashPlayer.plugin in Electron: can't install Adobe AIR as hard disk is not available

Tags: flash, electron, air, adobe

I have an Electron app that opens a flash app inside a webview.

- Electron version: 5.0.1
- PepperFlashPlayer.plugin version (mac):
  32.0.0.101

From flash app I can open another app written in Adobe AIR. If Adobe AIR in not installed, I get a prompt to install Adobe AIR, but installation fails.

Adobe AIR Installer error:

> Couldn't write the application to the hard disk. Please verify the
> hard disk is available and try again.

This works if I a open this flash app inside a browser but doesn't if this is opened inside a webview from Electron.

I stumbled across this project: https://github.com/szwacz/nw-flash-trust that would make Flash plugins trusted, but that should not be the reason I guess as my flash app is not local or loaded from file:// protocol, but is loaded from a web server.

Any ideas how to grant flash app inside a webviw in Electron write permissions so Adobe AIR can be downloaded and installed?

Comment: This is quite ambiguous. Are you trying to run .swf file OR are you trying to run AIR app?
If you are trying to run SWF file inside WebKit  , then users must have installed Flash Player plugin (and NOT Adobe AIR) on their computer. yes, this is the new policy since v~25 or so.

Can you please clarify what you are gonna do?

Comment: I'm already running swf inside webkit (using pepper flash). This works without problems.
Inside this running swf there is a trigger that opens an AIR app installed on a computer. If AIR is not installed on a computer, swf triggers native flash interface to download and install Adobe AIR. At this moment I get the above error saying hard disk is not available.

Comment: Well, for that purpose I can only suggest different approach: First, by telling the users to manually install the AIR runtime. Second , re-build apps thats writte in AIR using captive runtime instead